# Creating a custom plot function with pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I would like to define a function taking in input `ax` and plotting data on it.

My quick dummy example, working on spyder 4 (backend: PyQT5):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def func(L, ax):
    L_modified = [x+k for k, x in enumerate(L)]
    ax.plot(L_modified)
    return L_modified

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data = func(L, ax)
```

And that works fine, `data` is a list containing the modified input; and a plot appears correctly. On different post/explanation, I see that the function drawing the plot usually returns `ax`, which is not my case. Is it necessary to return `ax` to have this type of function work for every IDE? Is it working only because I'm using spyder?

As my question syntax seems a little too broad for some, here is the big all-in-one: **What is the best way to create a custom plotting function?**

**EDIT: Example where I create a figure if needed**

```
def butter_lowpass_filter(self, cutoff, order=5, plot=False, ax=None, **plt_kwargs):
    nyq = 0.5 * self.fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    data_filtered = lfilter(b, a, self.data)
    
    if plot is True:
        if ax is None:
            f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(15, 10))
            f.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0.15)
            ax[0].plot(self.data, color='blue')
            ax[0].plot(data_filtered, color='teal')
            ax[0].set_title("Signal + Fitlered signal")
            ax[1].plot(data_filtered, color='teal')
            ax[1].set_title("Filtered signal with a Butterworth filter")
        
        else:
            ax.plot(data_filtered, **plt_kwargs)
            ax.set_title("Filtered signal with a Butterworth filter")
    
    return data_filtered
```

Comment: There is no best way. Since the example you give only plots onto an existing axes (i.e. doesn't create a new figure and axes if one isn't passed to it) then there is no need to return the axes

Comment: @DavidG Thank you. Then what if inside the function I create a figure and an axes when the argument `ax` is set to None. Do I need to return them (and what would I do with them), OR is the figure/axes automatically displayed?

Comment: @DavidG I added an example from my current work

Comment: Just return it. Try `import this` and look at the second point: *Explicit is better than implicit.* It is never a bad idea to explicitly return it. If you want to alter ax properties, such as labels, limits etc. (which you will be doing in 99.99% of the time for publication quality figures), then having an explicitly returned axes instance makes life much easier.

Comment: @Scotty1- Still not clear why it's needed. For instance, if I create the figure and axes, then call my plotting function on this ax (which will plot `data_filtered` and add the title `'Filtered signal ..."`), and then decide to overwrite this title, I can simply write `ax.set_title("my new title")` after and it will overwrite what was set in the function. It looks to me like since I define the ax outside the scope of the function anyway, I don't need to return it as it is already present in the working scope.

Comment: @Scotty1- Oh now I think I get it. It needs to be return for the case I create the ax inside the function, when I don't give an ax as an input!

Comment: Yup. So if you want to set plot properties outside of the function, f.i. `ax.set_ylim(0, 1)`, then it is good to have an explicit ax handle. At least I prefer the explicit ax handle over f.i. `plt.set_ylim` or `ax = plt.gca(); ax.set_ylim()...` etc.

Comment: @Scotty1- I agree, I prefer this syntax too. Thank you, now I have a far better understanding of it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand what you are looking for.  I suppose you want a function that modifies a figure.  There are two versions of the code, the second being slightly commented and an improvement of the first.

1. I don't use spyder (only the terminal) and I have no graphical result for your code.
2. In general, I think it's a good practice, in case you use `matplotlib`, to completely define the graphical window (the figure) and to not leave python doing the job behind the scene.  You'll need the definition if the program gets complicated.

- name of the figure is important
- fig.add_subplot in case you use more than one coordinate systems
- try to fix the axes' boundaries according to your graphical objects

3. I wrote down a minimal example starting from yours.  It is based on your function which is called more than one time.  So the image evolves.  Now, what you get is some rudimentary animation.  But, even so, there are many flaws as you can easily see:

- the axes are not stable
- the graphs are piling up.

The function should be improved; since I don't know if I go in the right direction, I stop here for the moment.

4. Why does the function return that list anyway?

**First version**

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time

def func(L, fig):
    L_modified = [x+k for k, x in enumerate(L)]
    ax = fig.axes[0]
    ax.plot(L_modified)
    return L_modified

plt.ion()
delta_t = .5

f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = f.add_subplot(1,1,1, aspect='equal')

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data = func(L, f)
plt.pause(delta_t)

for j in range(len(L)):
    L[j] = L[j]-3*(j+1) 
    data = func(L, f)
    plt.pause(delta_t)
    f.show()

plt.show(block=True)
```

**Second, improved, and commented version** of the code.
I'm using also the output of the function, let's say.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time

# I modified the function such that the graphical changes that it induces
# are all realised when the function is called.
def func(L, fig): 
    L_modified = [x+k for k, x in enumerate(L)]
    ax = fig.axes[0]
    curves = ax.get_lines()  # list of curves in axes
    if len(curves)==0:
        ax.plot(L_modified)
    else:
        curves[-1].set_ydata(L_modified)  # modify the y data of the curve
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(delta_t)  # pause for delta_t seconds
    return L_modified

plt.ion()  # turn the interactive mode on.

f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = f.add_subplot(1,1,1, aspect='equal')
ax.set(xlim=(-1, 5), ylim=(-5.25, 9.25))  # fix the drawing region

delta_t = .5
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data = func(L, f)
plt.pause(delta_t)  # pause for delta_t seconds

for j in range(len(L)):
    L[j] = -data[j] 
    data = func(L, f)
    
plt.show(block=True)
'''
Display all open figures and change block to True; it was on False due
to plt.ion().
'''
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Good to know that my current solution isn't robust and doesn't work outside an IDE like spyder. If you have a look at the dummy example, of course the list returned is not important. In the real one below, the return is the filtered data after a Butterworth filter. With the comments from other people, I have a better understanding of when I need to return the `ax` (or fig). Could you detail a bit the lines completely define the graphical window (i.e. to make it work outside an IDE)?

Comment: Moreover, I dislike the `plt.command()` syntax as it isn't explicit. What is the `pause`, the `show` referring to? Could we change `plt` by the figure variable `f`?

Comment: OK.  I modified the answer and the code also (I added a new version of the first one).  Don't forget, I'm not a python expert!